# How to resolve twitter api rate limit?

Tags: python, api, twitter, python-3.5

Using `pip3 install twitter` for a small Python program to retrieve all user's tweets in total year.

```
utl = t.statuses.user_timeline(count = n, screen_name = name)
```

Got a error about rate limits, as it shows:

> details: {'errors': [{'code': 88, 'message': 'Rate limit exceeded'}]}

After checking api docs, https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting, but no idea how to fix it.

Hopefully, anyone could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [rate limit page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits.html) is quite clear, you are restricted to making 180 calls per 15 minutes.

This gives you a few options.

- Throttle your code.  Put a `sleep` in there to ensure it never exceeds the limit.
- Use the API options to get the maximum amount of data in the shortest amount of API calls.

The [documentation for statuses/user_timeline](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline) says:

> This method can only return up to 3,200 of a user’s most recent Tweets.

and

> `count` Specifies the number of tweets to try and retrieve, up to a maximum of 200 per distinct request.

So you can use `count=200` to request all 3,200 statuses in just **16 API calls**.

Comment: Also from the rate limit page, if you use application authentication your limit is 300 calls in each 15 minute window -- useful if you want to speed this process up.

Comment: I could hardly notice this limit of of `3200` without your mention. Is there a workaround  to beyond it? My intention is to get someone's all tweets, more than 10K, in one year. Now I use 200 tweets retrieved every time, but as limited you mentioned, only 3245 tweets could be received.